# Change Column name of a dataset in R

Tags: r

I'm a complete newbie and am trying to change column names of a dataset in R.  For example, to change the column name of 'Eth' in dataset quine to 'Ethnic'.  Any help or the name of the function is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The function 'colnames' is what you're looking for

let's say that 'Eth' is the third column, do

```
colnames(dataset)[3]<-"Ethnic"
```

colnames(dataset) returns exactly what you think it should, but you can also use it to set column names.

Doing the following

```
colnames(dataset)<-newColNames
```

where newColNames is a vector of names of the same length as the number of columns in dataset will change all the column names in order.

The following (as I did above)

```
colnames(dataset)[i]<-name
```

where name is a string and i is an integer, will change the name of the ith column to whatever the string "name" is